# using bezier curves

Tags: html, canvas, bezier, polygons

I'm creating one custom method for my project which will create polygons.
I have this:

```
var c2 = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
c2.beginPath();
c2.moveTo(10, 20);
c2.lineTo(20, 10);
c2.lineTo(60, 10);
c2.lineTo(60, 30);
c2.lineTo(20, 30);
c2.lineTo(10, 20);
c2.closePath();
c2.fill();
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yd7Wv/4292/
Now, I need use bezier curves because **I need rounded edges**
Could you help me with bezier curves, please?
Best regards, Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw bezier curve using

```
canvas_context.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, x, y);
```

and

```
canvas_context.quadraticCurveTo(cpx, cpy, x, y);
```

these docs will help you

1. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/
2. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element

Comment: if you are satisfied with this ans then plz accept it, so that other can follow this ans without any hesitation,

Answer (score 3):

Either use the `bezierCurveTo` method already implemented:

```
bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, x, y);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp

Or you can write your own bazier curve method like the one below, which has a much greater approximation:

```
coord = function (x,y) {
  if(!x) var x=0;
  if(!y) var y=0;
  return {x: x, y: y};
}

function B1(t) { return t*t*t }
function B2(t) { return 3*t*t*(1-t) }
function B3(t) { return 3*t*(1-t)*(1-t) }
function B4(t) { return (1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t) }

function getBezier(percent,C1,C2,C3,C4) {
  var pos = new coord();
  pos.x = C1.x*B1(percent) + C2.x*B2(percent) + C3.x*B3(percent) + C4.x*B4(percent);
  pos.y = C1.y*B1(percent) + C2.y*B2(percent) + C3.y*B3(percent) + C4.y*B4(percent);
  return pos;
}
```

Comment: Hi man, sorry...yes, I accepted it because after it, I obtained it...but I used stroke in order to paint a border, and I also used linejoin='round' to make the border rounded....thanks dear!